# "stick" jobs to the master

Tags: jenkins

I'm running jenkins 1.455. I have a master and a few slaves.
I use labels on the builds and have the slaves set to "leave this machine for tied jobs only", everything works fine.
However, I would like to do the inverse and set the slaves to "utilize this slave as much as possible and have only a couple of builds on the master.  Can I use "master" as a label in the "Restrict where this project can be run" field?

Comment: Ah yes i can see how you do it now.  go to manage jenkins -> configure system and set the label and usage just like any other node

Comment: You do not even have to do that - just type in 'master'

Answer (score 21):

Tell Jenkins to run a specific job only on the master node by configuring that job to `restrict where this project can be run` and setting the label to `master`.

Open the configuration panel for your job, under the `General` section:
[image: set jenkins node label expression to master]

Set the label to `!master` to restrict the job to run only on slave nodes.